# Copy database with data and foreign keys without identity insert on

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, sql-server-2012

Scenario:

I have a set of test data that needs to be deployed to our build server daily (our build server database is first overwritten with the current live database, and has all data over a month old removed).

This test data has foreign key references within it which need to stay.

I can't simply switch on IDENTITY_INSERT as the primary keys may clash with data that is already in the database (because we aren't starting from a blank database).

The test data needs to be able to be regenerated fairly regularly, so the though of going through the deploy script and fudging the id columns to be something outlandish (or a negative number for instance) and then changing the related foreign key columns to be the same id every time we regenerate the data doesn't thrill me.

Ideally I would like to know if there is a tool which can scan a database, pick up the foreign key constraints and generate the insert scripts accordingly, something like:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES('TEST','TEST');

DECLARE @Id INT;
SET @Id = (SELECT @@IDENTITY)

INSERT INTO MyRelatedTable VALUES(@Id,'TEST')
```

Comment: What sort of testing are you trying to do here? I would've thought that for a test system, you'd always want to load it with a given, known, set of data - how else will the expected results of your tests be kept fresh?

Comment: In order to ensure that current live data isn't causing any issues our tests also scan through that data (that's why we only wipe out data older than a month on the build server). As you say though, the idea behind loading the known data is so the tests we run against that data will be able to assert if the counts and values are correct.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to look into an ETL process that copes with the change in id. As you're using SQL Server, you can look at the [`OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177564.aspx) - use this to build up some temporary tables that can map the "old" id to the "new" id for each primary key to map the foreign keys when migrating the "child" tables.